# I want to delete the list of data using JPA in spring boot. By using deleteById I can able to delete only the data but I want to delete a list of data

Tags: spring-boot

By using deletebById I can able to delete the data with the given id.
By using deleteAll I can able to delete the overall data.
Now I want to delete the list of data. for example I want to delete the data from id:3 to id:10.
How can I implement the logic. Can anyone help me

I dont know how to perform the logic of deleting the list of data

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to delete itmes using Spring Data JPA, but the [Jpa Query Methods](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/reference/jpa/query-methods.html) is the simplest to implement.

```java
public interface YourEntityRepository extends JpaRepository<YourEntity, Long> {
    void deleteByIdIn(List<Long> ids);
}
```

(above code, JpaRepository's second generic type is the type of YourEntity's id)

You can use like

```java
@Component
public class SomeClass {
    private final YourEntityRepository repo;

    public SomeClass(YourEntityRepository repo) { this.repo = repo; }

    public void foo(List<Long> ids) {
        repo.deleteByIdIn(ids);
    }
}
```

I recommend reading the official document and getting a little more conceptual.